# ESAPI not passing file validation

Tags: java, regex, validation, path, esapi

I am working with ESAPI to try and validate windows directory paths. For some reason, the part of my directory path named \14\ is getting converted into a CRLF. The error I am receiving is below, what am I not understanding correctly? I feel like my regex should be working.

```
WARN  IntrusionDetector [SECURITY FAILURE Anonymous:null@unknown -> /project-test/IntrusionDetector] Invalid input: context=directoryPath, type(DirectoryName)=^[a-zA-Z0-9:/\\!@#$%^&{}\[\]()_+\-=,.~'` ]{1,255}$, input=C:\UsersTESTUS~1AppDataLocalTempTestCase8002TempWorkSpace, orig=C:\Users\TESTUS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\14\TestCase8002TempWorkSpace
```

As you can see, I am using the regex:
**^[a-zA-Z0-9:/\!@#$%^&{}[]()_+-=,.~'` ]$**

My input is: 
**C:\Users\TESTUS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\14\TestCase8002TempWorkSpace**

Ouput, after ESAPI does canonicalization and validation: 
**C:\UsersTESTUS~1AppDataLocalTempTestCase8002TempWorkSpace**

Here is the line of code that causes me to receive the error;

```
String validatedSourcePath = ESAPI.validator().getValidInput("directoryUnzip", directory, "DirectoryName", 255, false);
File validFile = new File(validatedSourcePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

@C.Williams: I was about 30 minutes into writing up a detailed reply in an editor and accidentally excited my editor window. I'm too ticked off at my stupidity of not saving it to write it again, especially since I was only about 75% done.

However, if you want to email me I can arrange to talk to you via Google Hangouts or Signal to tell you want your problem is and how you can fix it. But it's long and complicated and partially related to a bug the ESAPI team just fixed but is not in any official release yet. But I am not going to take another 45 minutes or more trying to reply with any written text. My email address should be easy enough to find. Just google for my name and ESAPI. I am one of the project co-leaders on ESAPI.

-kevin wall

Comment: Hi Kevin, I've sent you an email at the gmail I found on an old github issue: " First 3.0.0 release date? #3 "

Comment: We haven't even started on 3.0 yet. It basically will be a complete rewrite and we suspect that a lot of the interfaces will change, so we probably will rename the base package to something like "org.owasp.esapi3" when we do to provide a migration path. Right now, we are trying to get Maven working so we can release 2.2.0.0.